# repeat a wget (or curl) download infinitely

Tags: curl, applescript, wget

I'm stuck with the following problem:

I want **`wget`** (or **`curl`**, whatever may be suitable) to repeatedly check a folder for new files, and if there are, download them.

The thing is that: at some point `wget` always thinks, it's *"done"*. i already tried

```
-r -nc -nd
```

and also

```
-t 0
```

options; but I can't get it to work.

### Background

I have a GoPro (which can be accessed via Wi-Fi). I want to use as webcam in such a way as it repeatedly takes photos. I can get **`wget`** to download the files from the GoPro, but i need this progress to be repeated as long as the GoPro takes photos.

As next step i want **`curl`** to always take the latest photo, rename it to, say, `default.jpg` and upload it to an ftp server, where it is always overwritten. But i would be happy with that **`wget`** problem already ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the `watch` command. 
http://www.linfo.org/watch.html

Syntax: `watch [option(s)] command`

By simply calling `watch [your wget here]`, your command will automatically be run every two seconds until you `CTRL+C` out of it.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, but my terminal says "command not found", maybe because i'm on a mac?

Comment: Hey, for a MAC implementation of the same functionality you may call
`while :; do clear; your_command; sleep 2; done` which does basically the same as a naked watch command. Good luck, and in the future please remember to specify the system you're working on! :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I managed it via repeat & delay from applescript, which does not appear to be very elegant, but works, now for the upload part!